# Elasticsearch doesn't work with an slash at beginning

Tags: string, elasticsearch, search, filter, nosql

My db is filled with documents like this:

```
{
  _index: "bla_bla",
  .
  .
  .
  _source: {
    domain: "somedomain.extension",
    path: "/you/know/the/path",
    lang: "en",
    keywords: ["yeah", "you", "rock", "dude", "help", "me", "good", "samaritan"]
  }
}
```

When I search -- regardless what I looking for -- it works like a charm, but, if I try to filter something by using the field called **path** it -- simply -- doesn't work; not a single error or warning is thrown. After an exhausting research I guess it's because the slash at the beginning of the paths, may I'm right or not but anyway I need to filter like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": {
                        "terms": {
                            "keywords": ["stackoverflow", "rocks", "!"]
                        }
                    },
                    "must_not": {
                        "term": {
                            "path": "/"
                            // This works, i.e -> "lang": "en"
                        }
                    }
                }       
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 9
}
```

**TL;DR**: Having a database of **urls**, how can I get only the **non-root** [with a path longer than "/"] ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I'm no expert regarding ES, but If understand it correctly what you want is to exclude all the documents which only have `/`. In the end. Seeing that you always store your data as `/path` if you have a string with 1 character it should always be `/`, so why not use regular expressions?

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-filter.html

Something like this should do the trick, I think:

```
    {
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "keywords": [
                                        "stackoverflow",
                                        "rocks",
                                        "!"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "filter": {
                            "regexp": {
                                "path": ".{1,}"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 9
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In ElasticSearch, text is split on many characters, including slashes.  What you need to do is use a "not_analyzed" index.  Here is a working sample, notice the index specification on the "path" field:

```
PUT /index1/test/_mapping
{
    "test" : {
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {"type" : "string"},
            "path" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        }
    }
}

POST index1/test
{
  "path" : "/foo/bar"  
}

GET index1/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "path": "/foo/bar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I easily change this param of the mapping? @jhilden

Comment: If you PUT a updated mapping it will apply for all new data, but in order to apply to existing data you'll need to reindex. There are many posts to help with that task.